# How to execute code in init block after property y is initialized

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I would like to call some code inside my class init block, after a property y is initialized. I've tried it with `this::y.isInitialized` ..., but the problem here is that at the creation of the class, the property is not initialized (which it gets during runtime).

### ExampleClass

```
class Example {
     lateinit var y: String // this gets initialized after the creation of the fragment at a later time

     init {
         if(this::y.isInitialized) {
            doStuff()
         }
     }

}
```

### Szenario

```
val testObject = Example()
testObject.y = "START INIT CODE" // here it should execute the init block
```

Is this even possible? Or should I change the init block with a function call after I ensure that `y` is initialized?

Comment: you could use [observer pattern](https://kotlin-code.com/design-patterns/behavioral-patterns/observer-pattern/). In the comment yuo mention fragment - are you writing for Android? if yes you could use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Comment: Yes in this example I am writing for android. But moreover, I am interested in a general solution

Answer (score 1):

The `init` block is exclusively for code called at instantiation time, so it is not applicable to something that is `lateinit`.

I also have to mention, a public `lateinit var` in my opinion is a huge code smell. There's no way to force outside classes to treat it appropriately at compile time. `lateinit` is intended for properties that are only usable (visible) after some post-construction event.

Assuming we don't care about the design issue, one way you could solve it is with a second nullable backing property.

```
class Example {
    private var _y: String? = null
        set(value) {
            val needInitialization = field == null
            field = value
            if (needInitialization) {
                // do initialization work here
            }
        }
    
    var y: String
        get() = _y ?: throw UninitializedPropertyAccessException("y must be initialized before getting.")
        set(value) {
            _y = value
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that it is a design issue in my case. My ExampleClass is only used inside on other class and I know that I have to assign the lateinit property inside this other class.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
class Example {

    var y: String = "UNINITIALIZED"
        set(value) {
            if (field == "UNINITIALIZED") doStuff(value)
            field = value
        }

    fun doStuff(y: String) {...}
}
```

or if you need to modify the initial value:

```
class Example {

    var y: String = "UNINITIALIZED"
        set(value) {
            field = if (field == "UNINITIALIZED") doStuff(value) else value
        }

    fun doStuff(y: String): String {...}

}
```

Comment: the doStuff() method uses the property y. Is this still possible?

Comment: it uses the getter or setter?

Comment: the getter. DoStuff() needs the value of y in order to execute properly

Comment: you can use "value" instead of the getter

Comment: I gave you a more complete answer now

Answer (score 0):

You can use an observable property delegate for this purpose. Here's an example:

```
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

class Example {
    var y: Int? by Delegates.observable(initialValue = null) { _, oldValue, _ ->
        if (oldValue == null) {
            doStuff()
        }
    }

    private fun doStuff() {}
}
```

If you need more sophisticated logic, like to allow assigning property only once, you may want to implement your own [property delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) similar to the proposed.